# Python newbie does not understand why his comparison doesnt work

Tags: python

So i've set myself the goal of learning programming with Python. I've started about 3 days ago and decided to start with a random number generating game as a starting Project.
The problem i have with my code is that my make_try method isn't giving me the right outputs. It just always goes with the else statement, even if the comparison in the if statement should be right. I personally am very frustrated right now and i hope you can help me.
Greetings Marc

```py
import random

class Test:


    def __init__(self):

        self.number1 = random.randrange(1, 20)
        self.score = 100

    
    def first_tip(self):

        print(self.number1)

        if(self.number1 % 2 == 0 and self.number1 <= 10):
            print("Your number is even and smaller than 10")
        elif(self.number1 % 2 == 0 and self.number1 >= 10):
            print("Your number is even and bigger than 10")
        elif(self.number1 % 2 != 0 and self.number1 <= 10):
            print("Your number is uneven and smaller than 10")
        elif(self.number1 % 2 != 0 and self.number1 >= 10):
            print("Your number is uneven and bigger than 10")


    def make_try(self):
        
        print("My guess would be:")
        testguess = input()    
    
        if(self.number1 == testguess):

            new_score = self.score + 100
            print("*****************")
            print("*Congratulations*")
            print("*****************")
            print(f"Your final score: {new_score}")  
            
        else:
            
            new_score = self.score -10
            print("Wrong!")
            print(f"Your new score: {new_score}")
            x = input("Try again?(Yes/No)")
            print(x) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    T1 = Test()
    
    T1.first_tip() 
    T1.make_try()
```

Comment: You're trying to perform arithmetic comparisons against strings

Comment: Default `input` is in string. Convert it to integer by `testguess = int(input())`

Comment: A good thing to learn is how to debug your code. The `input()` command returns a `string`. Comparing it with an `int` would return `False`.

Comment: It's as @ArthurKing notes: the `input()` function always returns a string, which can not be equal to an integer (Python has dynamic but "strong" types, it rarely if ever performs conversions implicitely). So you need to convert `testguess` to an integer (and probably correctly handle the cases where nonsense was input).

Answer (score 1):

You have different types in your comparison

`testguess = input()` means that `testguess` is a string

`self.number1 = random.randrange(1, 20)` means that `self.number1` is an integer

simplest way to fix this is by: `testguess = int(input())`

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Works perfectly fine like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is input types, thats why as a newbie I would probably recommend C# or C++ bc you have more or total control over your types,

To fix this problem of your I simply added a cast to this line, and it works properly

```
 if(self.number1 == int(testguess)):
```